# global variable going null outside function

Tags: c

I'm extremely new to C, so I'm sure this is really easy.

I'm trying to declare an `array[10]` of fractions in a header file and define it as a static variable in my `example.c` file.  I initialize it in my function init_heap().  All elements of the array are null when that function returns, however.  How do I do this properly?  I need the changes to myArray to stick.

Header snippet:

```
struct fraction
{
    signed char sign;
    unsigned int numerator;
    unsigned int denominator;
};

extern struct fraction *myArray[10];
```

*example.c*:

```
//includes...

static struct fraction *myArray[10];


void init_heap()
{
    struct fraction myArray[] = {
        {0,0,1},
        {0,0,2},
        {0,0,3},
        {0,0,4},
        {0,0,5},
        {0,0,6},
        {0,0,7},
        {0,0,8},
        {0,0,9},
        {0,0,10}
    };
    beginFreeIndex = 0;
}
//etc...
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why you use an initializing declaration and so avoid the need for the init_heap() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct fraction myArray[] = {
    {0,0,1},
    {0,0,2},
    {0,0,3},
    {0,0,4},
    {0,0,5},
    {0,0,6},
    {0,0,7},
    {0,0,8},
    {0,0,9},
    {0,0,10}
};
```

You're making a local array called `myArray` which is hiding the global `myArray`. Then, when your function ends, the local `myArray` goes out of scope and you lose everything. Meanwhile, the global `myArray` is still null.

Try:

```
    myArray = {
    {0,0,1},
    {0,0,2},
    {0,0,3},
    {0,0,4},
    {0,0,5},
    {0,0,6},
    {0,0,7},
    {0,0,8},
    {0,0,9},
    {0,0,10}
    };
```

EDIT:

As @David Heffernan points out, you're declaring an array of pointers to `struct fraction` in this line: `extern struct fraction *myArray[10];`. I think you're trying to get just an array of `struct fraction`, so you should try this instead in place of that line: `extern struct fraction myArray[10]`

Comment: The global array `myArray` is an array of pointers to struct. That needs to be changed I think.

Comment: @Tushar When I do that I get an error on myArray "exxpression must be a modifiable value"